# How to fix "Optimization Opportunities"

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, uiview

I'm using xcode 12.
I wrote extension UI View as below:

```
@IBInspectable
public var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.shadowRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowRadius = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable
public var shadowOpacity: Float {
    get {
        return layer.shadowOpacity
    }
    set {
         layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable
public var shadowOffset: CGSize {
    get {
        layer.shadowOffset
    }
    set {
         layer.shadowOffset = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable
public var shadowColor: UIColor {
    get {
        return UIColor(cgColor: layer.shadowColor ?? UIColor.clear.cgColor)
    }
    
    set {
        layer.shadowColor = newValue.cgColor
    }
}
```

Things works fine but when I debug view, I saw some purple warnings like this.

> x-xcode-debug-views://7f8fd2258020?DBGViewDebuggerLaunchSessionParameter=7f8fd2258020:
> runtime: Optimization Opportunities: The layer is using dynamic
> shadows which are expensive to render. If possible try setting
> `shadowPath`, or pre-rendering the shadow into an image and putting it
> under the layer.

Can someone explain this to me and help me to get rid of it??

[image: Here are the purple warnings]

Comment: Thanks for the question, I have the same question too, but how do we know which layer to work on? there's no indication in the error message

Comment: @StackGU while running the app, open the Debug View Hierarchy. In the left pane, you will see a purple exclamation mark next to the view (and it's parents) with the issue.

Answer (score 20):

## Setting shadowPath

One solution is to "guide" the shadow rendering by setting the `shadowPath` explicitly to your needs, eg.:

```
yourViewWithShadow.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: yourViewWithShadow.bounds).cgPath
```

*Make sure you're setting the frame at the right time!*

## Cache rasterization

Another solution is to cache the rasterization:

```
yourViewWithShadow.layer.shouldRasterize = true
yourViewWithShadow.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

Hope this helps you to eliminate expensive calculations.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried setting the shadowPath and the shadow no longer appears.  I then tried the cache rasterization option and whilst the shadow shows again, so does the optimization opportunity warning.

Comment: Enabling rasterization does not resolve this problem.

Comment: Rasterization will prevent UIKit from rendering the shadow again and again whenever the view's frame changes. But for the first time rendering, the shadow is still dynamically rendered, which is expensive. In short, rasterization does optimize the performance in some use cases, but the view still has opportunities for further optimization.

Comment: Adding this distorts the shadow :(